# Get exception at `CTFontManagerRegisterFontsForURL`

Tags: objective-c

```
@implementation UIFont (FlatUI)

+ (void) initialize {
    [super initialize];
    static dispatch_once_t onceToken;
    dispatch_once(&onceToken, ^{
        NSArray *fontNames = @[@"Lato-Regular", @"Lato-Bold", @"Lato-Italic", @"Lato-Light"];
        for (NSString *fontName in fontNames) {
            NSURL * url = [[NSBundle mainBundle] URLForResource:fontName withExtension:@"ttf"];
            if (url) {
                CFErrorRef error;
                CTFontManagerRegisterFontsForURL((__bridge CFURLRef)url, kCTFontManagerScopeNone, &error);
            }
        }
    });
}
```

I add exception breakpoint, and every time it gets exception at `CTFontManagerRegisterFontsForURL((__bridge CFURLRef)url, kCTFontManagerScopeNone, &error);`
How to solve it?[image]

EDIT:[image]

Comment: Can you continue or is it a fatal crash?

Comment: @rmaddy No. I've edited the question's code. Even when I removed `initialize`, it still catch an exception at `return UIApplicationMain(argc, argv, nil, NSStringFromClass([AppDelegate class]));`

Comment: @Gank You're not answering the question.

Comment: I've solved it: https://github.com/Grouper/FlatUIKit/issues/184#issuecomment-99909960

Answer (score 4):

There might be nothing to solve. Hitting an exception breakpoint doesn't mean your app crashes. The exception might be caught internally and the app continues just fine. So the fact that you hit an exception breakpoint might not matter. The question is what happens if you continue, or if you just disable the exception breakpoint entirely. If you *don't* crash when the exception breakpoint is *disabled*, then you should just *ignore* the fact that you pause there when it is *enabled*.